# Passing data from child to parent component in angular via <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, components, parameter-passing, eventemitter

In app.component.html I have

```
<div>
    <app-login (un)="doSth($event)"></app-login>
</div>
<router-outlet (un)="doSth($event)"></router-outlet>
```

and in app.component.ts I have

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'order';
  uname = 'guest';

  doSth (name:any) {
    console.log("name", name);
    this.uname = name;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that I get data to app.component.ts when I use tag `<app-login>`, but not when I use tag `<router-outlet>`. Why is that and how do I fix that?

Comment: Just use a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the router can do this.

What you would need to send messages across your application would be a state management store like NgRX.
But to make things simple you could also have a singleton subject where each one interested can subscribe to.

Example:
messaging.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessagingService {
  public messages$ = new Subject();
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'order';
  uname = 'guest';

  constructor(readonly messaging: MessagingService) {
    messaging.messages$.subscribe(event => {
      this.doSth(event);
    }
  }

  doSth (name:any) {
    console.log("name", name);
    this.uname = name;
  }
}
```

login.component.ts (and all the components you want in your `router-outlet`:

```
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private readonly messaging: MessagingService) {}

  iWantAppComponentToDoSth() {
     messaging.messages$.next({ name: 'foo' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Output in angular
In file `login.component.ts`.

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() un= new EventEmitter<any>();

// handle emit name form html
getName(event:any) {
 this.un.emit(event.tagret)
}
```